# Working in multiple languages/locales

Tags: microsoft-excel, locale

Is there any way to set the locale I want to use for a file in Excel?

This is my situation:

I normally work in multiple languages, which means different numbers, currency, dates representations, etc.
The worst is when I'm copy pasting data from language specific sources and I have to manually fix it.

Is there any way to tell Excel that a certain file is going to be worked in ES_es and another one in EN_us?

The only solution I find everywhere is to change the system locale, I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

For dates and times, you can try to select the cells that must be in another locale, then format them. On the Home tab, click on Number, then change the Date or Time locales.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: That is only going to fix the visualization if the data is correct, if I paste 14/03/2012 it's not going to consider it a date.

Answer (score 0):

Try a program such as [PureText](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/puretext/9pkjv6319qtl?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) to remove the formatting information
from the clipboard.

This might remove the language-dependent settings from the data currently
in the clipboard.
Better check that the copied data is correct, even if this seemed to work.

Comment: The problem is not really formatting, stripping the formatting from 14/03/2012 still does not make it a valid date for my system considering its locale is EN_us.

Comment: Try: (1) Using *Home > Paste > Paste Special* to paste as pure text, (2) After pasting use the Paste Options button to Match Destination Formatting.